# Separate Options class, overloaded constructor, or public properties with default values?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have been working on a project where I have a Worker class that generates a lot of data in a multi-threaded fashion.  The type, size, and location of the data is variable based on a large set of parameters that can be set by an end user.  Essentially this is a big test harness that I am using to investigate how certain things perform based on a variation of the data.  Right now I have at least 12 different parameters for the Worker class.  I was thinking about switching over to a separate WorkerOptions class that contains all of these values, and then have the UI create the WorkerOptions object and then pass that into the Worker.  However, I could also expose public properties on the Worker class to allow the options to be set appropriately at Worker creation as well.

What is the best way to go about this, and why?  I am sure this will generate some different opinions but I am open to listen to debate about why different people might do it a different way.  Some things to consider are that currently once a Worker is created and running, its configuration doesn't change unless it stops.  This could be subject to change, but I don't think it will.

**EDIT**
I am not a C# developer normally, I know enough to be able to write applications that function and follow common design patterns, but my expertise is in SQL Server, so I might ask follow up questions to clarify your meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd combine the two approaches.

Make your WorkerOptions class use a constructor that requires all the required parameters, and allows the optional parameters to be set either via an overload, optional arguments, or properties, then pass that in as an argument.

Having the WorkerOptions class gives you a nice DTO to pass around in case refactoring leads you to create an additional layer between the UI and the worker class itself. Using required parameters in its constructor gives you compile-time checking to prevent runtime errors.

Comment: As a plus you can encapsulate in WorkerOptions some logic for persisting a set of parameters (perhaps via serialization): that's very useful for testing many different sets of options in complex scenarios.

Comment: @Maghis: Yup. Having the parameters encapsulated can also be handy for logging: I often include a JSON string of a parameter object like this in logged error messages, which makes it much easier to track down the cause of bugs. In fact, I just got an error log message this morning that I was able to track down this way.

Answer (score 2):

I have as guideline that the parameters that are necessary to use the instance should be passed in the constructor and all 'optional' parameters should be properties.

The properties will be initialized of course in the constructor to their default values.

If the number of arguments is not high I use default value arguments, but 12 is quite some amount.

I forgot to mention the separate class for options. Mostly I don't do such thing, unless there is some 'business logic' inside the options (like checking if some option combinations are not possible). If it is just for storage, you end up a with a lot of extra references to this option class (instances).

Comment: All of the parameters have an initialized default value already, so the constructor is just changing a value from the default I established when creating them.  If I follow your advice correctly you are saying everything should be a public property, but that would/could allow the property to change unless I put checking logic in place for each property right?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, from what you have said, I prefer the WorkerOptions approach.  For the following reasons:

- It's cleaner, 12 constructor parameters is not out of the question, but it is perhaps a little excessive.
- You can apply polymorphism and all the other OO goodness to your WorkerOptions.  You might want to define an IWorkerOptions at some stage, or use [Builder](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBuilder.aspx) to construct different sub-classes of WorkerOption.

I would also make all WorkerOption instances immutable, or at least come up with a 'lock' or 'freeze' mechanism to prevent changes once a Worker has started execution.